# How to detect a chrome extension installed

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to detect if a chrome extension is installed or not.

For example the following code to detect Measureit. It add a div with id of shadowMeasureIt.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="chrome-webstore-item"
    href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aonjhmdcgbgikgjapjckfkefpphjpgma">

    <body>
<button onclick="chrome.webstore.install()" id="install-button">Add to Chrome</button>    
</body>
<script>

        if (document.getElementById('shadowMeasureIt')) {
  //document.getElementById('install-button').style.display = 'none';
  alert ("yes");
}
</script>
```

It does not work, but when I run the script in a console, it alerts "yes".

How can I make it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with this method :

`chrome.management.get(string id [, function callback])`

Exemple (**untested**):

`var myExtension = chrome.management.get( "my_extention_id" );

    if (myExtension.enabled)

    {

        // installed

    }

    else { ... }`
source : http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#method-get

Comment: The extension must have "permissions": [
    "management"
  ],in its manifest. Many don't have it.

Comment: I doubt there is any way to achieve it, if this is not your own extension with this permission flag. Example: in order to block AdBlock, some sites try to detect if the ad have been loaded. They don't try to know if AdBlock is installed. If there is any way to achive what you want to do, please let me know :)

Comment: @kekos91 it did not work for me, return this error: `cannot read property get of undefined` also I have management permission in my manifest

Answer (score 0):

```
chrome.management.get("extension_id",function (extensionInfo) {
    console.log(extensionInfo);
});
```

Must have "permissions": [ "management" ] in its manifest.

> extension_id would be the extension you would like to find.